# Save base64 data into a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64

I have seen couple of examples here and based on those examples I have prepared my solution. But still I am getting `Promise
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined`
I am trying to store my base 64 data into my base64 variable. Please let me know what's wrong with my code and a working solution.

Below is my try:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { DropzoneArea, DropzoneDialog } from 'material-ui-dropzone'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


async function getBaseData(selectedFile) {
    let base64;
    var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
    base64 = await getBase64(fileToLoad);
    return base64; //This returns me PromiseStatus Pending
}

function getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
        return Promise.resolve(reader.result)
    });
}

export class ImageUploader extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            files: [],
            image: null,
        };
    }
    handleImageChange(files) {
        const { imageCallback } = this.props
        imageCallback(getBaseData(files)); // By this callback i am trying to pass my base64 string to other component
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <DropzoneArea
                acceptedFiles={['image/*']}
                filesLimit={1}
                maxFileSize={10000000}
                //showPreviews={false}
                onChange={this.handleImageChange.bind(this)}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is getBaseData is an async function but you still need to wait for it to resolve.

Try "awaiting" for it as well like this:

```
handleImageChange(files) {
            const { imageCallback } = this.props;
            async function wrap(){
               const result = await getBaseData(files); //result should be a value here and not promise
               imageCallback(result);
            }
            wrap(); // call the async function which will await the getBaseData and use your callback

        }
```

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir Bogomolov for your help, I have tried this way i have changed my `function getBase64(file)` as @PrinceHernandez suggested and changed my handler exactly like this `handleImageChange(files) {
            const { imageCallback } = this.props;
            async function wrap(){
               const result = await getBaseData(files); 
               imageCallback(result);
            }
            wrap();

        }` but I am getting result empty string in my callback function. Kindly let me know what mistake I am making

Comment: Leave your function getBase64 as it was. I tested it with your code and my modification and it's working.

Comment: There is no need to `await` for the `Promise` to resolve; just chain it with a `.then(imageCallback)`

Answer (score 2):

your problem is how you are managing your `Promise`. you dont need to return anything from a Promise  as the [documentation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) or it will resolve inmediatly.

in this case when you do:

```
function getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
        return Promise.resolve(reader.result) // <--- this is wrong.
    });
}
```

it will resolve to `Promise.resolve(reader.result)` which is undefined, because maybe it didn't finish, maybe and just maybe you could get an accurate result but it is just luck that the `reader` actually resolves before that `return`(race condition)

basically in order to make it work, you need to use the `resolver` and the `rejecter` of the promise so it can resolve/reject.

EDIT: I noticed that you are also calling the reader function before setting the  callbacks, then you are reading the file, adding the callbacks and then the callbacks are not called.

just change your code to this:

```
function getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        //set the callbacks before reading the object
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result); 
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Prince Hernandez after trying this I am getting `Promise
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: ""` There is no value

Comment: I have tried in debug mode putting breakpoint at `resolve(reader.result)` and I got `Promise
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: "data:image/png;base64,iVBO...` but without debug mode PromiseValue is empty. any suggestions please?

Comment: sorry, there is another problem with your code, let me edit the question and add the correct steps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here: the creation of the `Promise` is incorrect, and you don't handle the resolved `Promise` as you should. There is no need for any `async` or `await` like other answers suggest.

The `Promise` creation:

```
function getBaseData(selectedFiles) {
    var fileToLoad = selectedFiles[0];
    return getBase64(fileToLoad);
}

function getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result); 
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

Resolving the `Promise`:

```
handleImageChange(files) {
    const { imageCallback } = this.props
    getBaseData(files).then(imageCallback);
}
```